# If $\forall x\in X,\; x\in U_x\subseteq X$, then $\bigcup_{x\in X}U_x=X$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Take any topological space $X$, is the following statement true? Let $x\in X$ and $U_x$ denote any open set containing $x$, then $\bigcup_{x\in X}U_x=X$. I want to use this statement in one of my proofs, but I'm not sure if this is true. but it seems to be reasonable.

Comment: All of the $x$s are in the union so $X$ is contained in the union. Each of the sets in the union are in $X$ so the union is contained in $X$.

Comment: By the way, this remains true if you change "open set" by "subset of $X$" and "topological space" with "set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\forall x\in X,\; \{x\}\subseteq U_x$. It then follows that $\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in X} U_x$. But $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ and thus $X\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in X} U_x$. The other inclusion follows from $\forall x\in X,\; U_x\subseteq X$. We conclude that $X=\bigcup_{x\in X} U_x$.

Intuitively, clearly $X$ is the set of all it's points. It follows that it is also the collection of all it's points and a little more (which is contained in $X$).